# Scala ArraySeq[Vector[data]]] processing

Tags: scala

I have below format of data:

```
ArraySeq(Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)), 
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)),
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)),
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)),
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)))
```

I want

```
Seq[None, None, None, None, None, Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(2.2),Some(2.2),Some(2.2),Some(2.2),Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(3.3), Some(3.3), Some(3.3),Some(3.3),Some(4.4), Some(4.4), Some(4.4), Some(4.4), Some(4.4)]
```

Comment: Sounds like `data.transpose.flatten` check the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/)

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiples solution :

```
s.transpose.flatten
```

The transpose method will pair and overlay elements from another collections into a single collection.
And flatten method are used to convert a list of lists into a single list.

A other solution available is use concatenation of foldLeft.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq;
val s = ArraySeq(Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)), 
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)),
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)),
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)),
Vector(None, Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(4.4)))

val result = s.foldLeft(Seq[Seq[Option[Double]]](Seq.empty[Option[Double]], Seq.empty[Option[Double]], Seq.empty[Option[Double]], Seq.empty[Option[Double]], Seq.empty[Option[Double]])) {
  case (acc, v) => Seq((acc(0) :+ v(0)), (acc(1) :+ v(1)), (acc(2) :+ v(2)), (acc(3) :+ v(3)), (acc(4) :+ v(4)))
}.foldLeft(Seq.empty[Option[Double]]) {
  case (acc, s) => acc ++ s
}


result are equal to => List(None, None, None, None, None, Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(1.1), Some(2.2), Some(2.2), Some(2.2), Some(2.2), Some(2.2), Some(3.3), Some(3.3), Some(3.3), Some(3.3), Some(3.3), Some(4.4), Some(4.4), Some(4.4), Some(4.4), Some(4.4))
```